# Solving Second Order ODEs with Singular Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having difficulties understanding the relevance of singular points in the solving of second order ODEs.

Take for instance, these two questions:

1. Solve the legendre equation:
   $$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+n(n+1)y=0$$
   With singular point $x=\pm1$
2. Determine the regular singular point of the differential equation:
   $$2x(x-1)y''+3 (x+1)y'-y=0$$

Please I will appreciate if you can explain your answers to me in simple layman's term.

Answer (score 0):

Those two equations are second order linear differential equations, which means that you need two initial conditions in order to find the a solution. For example for the first differential equation if you do not know the analytical solution you can approximate it with

$$
y'(x+h) = y'(x) + h y''(x) = y'(x) + h \frac{2xy'(x) - n(n+1)y(x)}{1-x^2},
$$

$$
y(x+h) = y(x) + h y'(x),
$$

which becomes more accurate as $h\to0$.

However at $x=\pm1$ $y''$ is equal to something divided by zero, which is not well defined.

Another way of looking at it is that at singular points the differential equation temporary decreases by one or more orders, allowing for less constraints, such has initial conditions.